# lld-link error when compiling C++ project with Clang in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-c++, clang, c++14

It is about one week which I am busy compiling my project with Clang in VS2019 but I cannot.
I update the VS2019 to the latest one and I am using Clang 12.00 now.

In my project, I am using boost library. To build boost library, I run these commands:

```
bootstrap --with-toolset=clang-win
b2.exe link=static threading=multi runtime-link=shared address-model=64 toolset=clang-win variant=release --build-type=complete --architecture=x64 cxxflags=-std=c++14
```

The compilation gives me this error:

```
1>lld-link : error : undefined symbol: __declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl boost::thread::~thread(void)
```

I thought that the boost library is incompatible. VS can find the boost libraries but I think it cannot read inside of that.

Comment: You might be trying to link Boost.Thread statically. This is unsupported, see e.g. https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/libs/config/doc/html/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that when you are using boost with clang you should set the `BOOST_THREAD_USE_LIB` flag in your code. So, I add the following Cmake code to my CmakeListss.txt file to the code and I could fix it.
`add_definitions(-DBOOST_THREAD_USE_LIB)`